# PHP multiple edit with checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a form which can edit/delete multiple rows in mysql database, for example is phpmy admin tabel editor:

[image]

So if i checked several data, and click change/edit, it will only show the checked data editor, like this:

[image]

and if i click delete, it will delete the checked data only, and if possible, i want the checked data to show in popup, instead in new page like if i use:

`<a href ='view2.php?id=$id'>Edit</a>`

I hope anyone can give me some solution or reference for my problem, thanks.

Comment: What you need is a [checkbox group](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create new checkbox column and new edit multi button below table.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>" name="chk[]">
```

User can be multi select checkbox. When submit button pressed, you get array User ID. array(1,2,3...)
You pass array into sql command, where ID in array above

I think that can be help you.

Comment: thank you very much, i take the basic from your answer, it's working.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ajax concept it will be useful to populate the data on the popup box which was requested by you.

```
<a class="popup" href ='view2.php' attr_id='<?php echo $id; ?>'>Edit</a>
```

Where the attr_id was the user defined attribute.

```
$('.popup').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+'YOUR_URL/'+$(this).attr('attr_id'),
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#content_popup').html(data);
                    }
            });
    });
```

Here you can use ajax to get the details. And load it on the #content_popup after that you can trigger to make #content_popup by using some plugins. (Fancybox,colorbox)